# Allow null in built-in JSX attributes with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I do a lot of:

```
<button onClick={disabled ? null : cb}>
```

Or:

```
function Button({ style = null }) {
  return <button style={style} />;
}
```

However, I'd get:

```
Type '(() => void) | null' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type '((event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.
```

For reference, from `@types/react`:

```
interface DOMAttributes<T> {
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler<T>;
}
```

I could fix this error by doing:

```
<button onClick={disabled ? undefined : cb}>
```

However, traditionally, we avoid using `undefined`. Is there a way to get TS to accept `null` in this case? Or more generally, if I can make TS consider `null` and `undefined` to be the same value, that'll help a lot. My code makes no distinction between the two.

I tried disabling `strictNullChecks`, but that didn't work.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about why "traditionally, we avoid using `undefined`"?

Comment: It's a variable that can be reassigned, so people used to prefer null. Also, I don't like it because it's harder to tell whether something was intentionally left empty or just not defined.

Comment: "if I can make TS consider null and undefined to be the same value" - they're _not_ the same value, though. They're often interchangeable, but certainly not in all situations. `JSON.stringify({ _: null }) !== JSON.stringify({ _: undefined })`

Comment: Why not just disable the button?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I made up an example while writing the question, this pattern is used throughout the codebase

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get TS to accept null in this case

Not without changing the type definitions, and I wouldn't recommend doing that.

## Solution

Just use `undefined`. Using both `null` and `undefined` is an inevitability of using JavaScript, especially when using the ecosystem packages that you are not the owner of (like react).